# Sort collection by date and time doesnt work

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to sort an array of objects by date and time, but isn't working.

My code is:

```
var dates = [
    {date: "15-12-2016 10:45"},
    {date: "18-12-2016 23:45"}
];

dates.sort(function(a, b){
     return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
});
```

Comment: Have you checked your console, wherever you are running this? `new Date("15-12-2016 10:45")` is invalid.

Comment: 15-12-2016 10:45 is not a valid argument for Date, you need to have a argument like `Sat Feb 04 2017 00:27:52 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`.Currently your new date returns invlaid date hence sorting doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You are using invalid date format.

Try to use:

```
var dates = [
    {date: "2016-11-15 10:45:00"},
    {date: "2016-11-18 23:45:00"}
];
```